# Configure remote debugger on F5 in VS

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, remote-debugging

I have the following setup:

1. Development machine with VS2015 (can be 2017 if it makes a difference).
2. Embedded device that runs Windows service in .NET. Device has remote debugging service configured and enabled.

Right now to debug the solution I need to:

1. Build solution on dev machine.
2. Log in remotely to device and execute deploy script.
3. Attach debugger to remote process.

However this is quite a lot of manual steps for every code change. Ideally I would just press F5 and debugger would hit my breakpoints.

I can automate executing deploy script (eg. specify program to start as psexec with arguments), but how do I tell VS which debugger it should use, which host to use, which process?

Answer (score 0):

As the configuration steps is needed while remote debugging, to use script to execute it, you can try the **shortcut keys** of the corresponding tabs of VS. For example, to open **Attach to process** window you could use **Ctrl + Alt + P**, for the process, you could find the **Process ID** in attach to process window which is same as the **PID in Task Manger -> Details**.